# IPFS content availability / health information

Tags: ipfs

### Is there a way to check how many nodes contain a specific content  ?

If an hashed content is stored on just a node and the node goes offline, the content will not be available anymore.

If on the other hand the content has previously been replicated on other nodes, when the first node goes offline the content is still available.

Comment: cf. https://ipfs-scan.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use  `ipfs dht findprovs` command for finding peers providing specific CID.